# How to derive Riemann-Lebesgue lemma from Bessel inequility?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I encountered Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma in Functional Analysis. It can be viewed as a corrollary of Bessel inequtility in the following picture:
[image]

However, I can't see why it is '**in particular**' ?  Can anyone give me some hint? My brain just short-circuit ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\left<x,x_k\right>|^2$ is **convergent** so its terms tend to zero, that is $\lim_{k\to\infty}|\left<x,x_k\right>|^2=0$.
Therefore $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left<x,x_k\right>=0$