# Riemann's Lemma as a corollary of Bessel's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series

I am learning about Fourier Series with Carother's Real Analysis. I'm currently stuck on the bolded statement below made by the author. First I will give a little context.

We have just proved the the partial Fourier sums of $f$ is the closest function to $f$ in the set of trigonometric polynomials of at most degree n. i.e
\begin{align} 
\underset{T \in T_{n}}{inf} ||f - T||_{2} = ||f(x) - S_{n}(f)||_{2}
\end{align}

We then used this to prove the following equality: 
\begin{align} 
||f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2} = ||f||_{2}^{2} - ||S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2}
\end{align}

We make the observation $||f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2}\geq 0$ to get Bessel's Inequality:
\begin{align}
||S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2} \leq ||f||_{2}^{2}
\end{align}

Because $n$ is arbitrary we can allow  $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence, 
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}^{2} + b_{k}^{2}) \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^{2}dx
\end{align}

This is the part I get confused at, when the author makes the following statement:

"**In particular, the Fourier Coefficients of $f$ must tend to zero:** 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(nx)dx = 0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)sin(nx)dx
\end{align}
**This fact is know as Riemann's lemma...**"

I can't seem to make this jump. I also looked at the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831070/how-to-derive-riemann-lebesgue-lemma-from-bessel-inequility) however, I still couldn't understand it. Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Fourier coefficients must tend to zero**
is a consequence of
$$
\frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}^{2} + b_{k}^{2}) < \infty ,
$$
which in turn follows from
$$
\frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}^{2} + b_{k}^{2}) \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^{2}dx ,
$$
since $f$ is square-integrable.  I'm guessing that square-integrablility is assumed somewhere above what you quoted.

Comment: Hi @GEdgar, thank you for your reply. I would like to clarify some of your points. Assuming we know that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^{2}dx$ is Riemann Integrable, we have that $\frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}^{2} + b_{k}^{2})$ = $\frac{1}{\pi}I$ $<$ $\infty$. This would imply the sum is convergent. The sum being convergent implies it's terms $\rightarrow 0$  as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Hence, $a_{k} \rightarrow 0$ and $b_{k} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$